# extremely slow head assets rendering in magento2 on windows

Tags: magento2, windows

I had to urgently migrate my working project from OSX machine to Windows10 box, and experienced terribly slow performance on loading magento pages (over 1 minute), with developer mode enabled.

After some debugging, I realized that timing issues came from this method

```
$this->pageConfigRenderer->renderHeadContent();
```

I had to make my changes fast and somehow continue my work so I just replaced `headContent` in `$this->assign()` method with pre-genared head contents of `renderHeadContent` and after that I got response time about 2-3seconds.

Did anyone struggled with similar problem before and found any workaround ?

(caching is enabled, varnish disabled)

my enviroment:

Windows 10

CPU: corei7 2.6

RAM: 6gb

SSD drive

wampserver (apache),
php7.0.10,
xdebug disabled,
opcache is not installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually this was the issue with css preprocessing/minifying but after lot of struggling with vagrant, virtualbox on windows environment turned that installing ubuntu on neighbor partition is the best option.